# Adding data-bind and static text in textarea using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout-2.0

I want to add both static text and a property to a text area. For example I want to display " [Development x] started work on [Start Date]" where Development_Name() and Start_Date() are properties that store the name and date respectively

This is what the text area looks like and the Development_Name() property works fine

```
<text area rows="6" class="textarea-box" id="txtComments" data-bind="Development_Name()"
```

How do I append static text to this. Doing it this way (below) is obviously incorrect

```
textarea rows="6" class="textarea-box" id="txtComments" data-bind="Development_Name()'+Started work on+'Start_Date()"></textarea>
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a method in the .js file and adding a data-bind value to it solves the problem.

Here's the view

```
<textarea rows="6" class="textarea-box" id="txtComments" data-bind="value: EmailBodyText"></textarea>
```

This is what the view model will look like

```
 SendEmail: function () {
        if (FlagResult() == "EI") {
           // $("#rowWrapParticipation").addClass('alert alert-danger');
            EmailBodyText("There was an attempt by your company to enter " + SponsorName() + "-" + $("#ddlDevelopment option:selected").text() + ". Unfortunately, at this time, you do not meet the controlled insurance program requirements to come onto the project site. Please contact Rebecca Osborne at Consolidated Risk Solutions via 678.893.7483 or rebecca.osborne@c-r-solutions.com to address this issue");
        }
```